# Require an argument depending on the presence of another argument

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Ther's some React functional component with several props.

```
interface Props {
  data?: any;
  status?: string;
}

const Component: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ data, status }) => {
  ...
};
```

I want the `status` prop to depend on the `data` prop, so you can't use `status` without `data`

```
<Component status={status} /> // error
<Component status={status} data={data} /> // ok
```

But you still can use `data` without `status`, or without props at all

```
<Component data={data} /> // ok
<Component /> // ok
```

Is it possible?
Is there a way to write an interface that meets these requirements?
Or maybe some other way?
I myself couldn't come to a solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a union type to model an object where if `status` is present and `string` then `data` must also be present.

```
type Props = {
  data: any;
  status?: string;
} | {
    status?: never
    data?: never
}

const Component: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ data, status }) => {
  
};
const status = "ok";
const data = [{}]

let x = <Component status={status} /> // error
let y = <Component status={status} data={data} /> // ok

let z = <Component data={data} /> // ok
let u = <Component /> // ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wCgYBPMJOABRzAGc4BeOAb1LjgBMUYUALjgoAdhQDcXOIwEwArowD8w2VGCiA5lIC+cAD4dp3Wf0Uq4opADckUY734oLV2-Z2lSaCKNlwAwriQVqIwwsjoMAB0AGLyohjAPoHgPkihADz0EEwAfKxwABTsjgIANDJyinA6AJSs+Zzc3EQKUKJwGbkZAPS5pDpS3r7wpgrMbABEEADWk0M+fnwCBQDa7DoAup4ANkjwAB4FGSnB6aNVjCzsY4p6fXA9PXB2OPZ78BTHp2mhlWZXG6XPTLFDXUH3fJPOCzXb7OAAL2+QV+8FB4KckMez1hHzg8mRqRC8Ae0NmQA)

Comment: It worked, but can you tell me why you used `never` in the second type?

Comment: In short, `never` type means "there's no value which can be put here", and optional property of type `never` means "you're not allowed to pass anything here, this property must be omitted".